# select all elements without someone in xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
<livre id="isbn-0-671-21280-X">
    <titre>How to Read a livre</titre>
    <Subtitre>The Classic Guide to Intelligent Reading</Subtitre>
    <Author>Mortimer J. Adler</Author>
    <Author>Charles Van Doren</Author>
    <Date>1940</Date>
    <Editeur>Simon &amp; Schuster</Editeur>
</livre>
```

how can I select all elements without Author?
so please if can someone help me, I will be thankful.
I'm trying to learn XPath and I'm blocked with this question.

Comment: hey bro can you help me with that problem please,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match in the example given? `livre` if it doesn't have an `Author`? All children of `livre` except `Author`?

Comment: i want to select all the children of livre except Author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath 2 and later allows you to literally select `* except Author` to select all child elements except the Author elements. In XPath 1 you can use `*[not(self::Author)]` to select all child elements that are not `Author` elements.